# Почему размер вектора в оперативной памяти значительно больше, чем после сохранения на диск? QT

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Я получаю по сокету данные несколько десятков раз в секунду, а именно структуру 140байт в виде QByteArray и помещаю это в вектор. Далее пишу содержимое в файл в другом классе(тоже в байтах). Проблема в том, что в оперативной памяти вектор занимает слишком много места(увеличивается на 50мб в минуту). Примерно в 10 раз больше, чем файл после записи на диск. Если же в к вектору применить vector.clear(); vector.squeeze(); то память освобождается. Но нужно решение по уменьшению объема в памяти, а не очищение.

```
socket.h


extern QVector<QByteArray> vector;
```

```
socket.cpp

QVector<QByteArray> vector;
//myStruct моя структура на 50+ элементов 
QByteArray array = socket->read(sizeof(myStruct));
vector.push_back(array);
```

```
file.cpp


file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

for (int i = 0; i<=vector.size()-1;i++)
  {
   myStruct* message = reinterpret_cast< myStruct*>(vector[i].data());
        writeMessage  = * message;
        out << writeMessage;
    }
    file.close();

    //writtenVector.clear();
    //writtenVector.squeeze();
```

Comment: А что возвращает метод `capacity`? Действительно ли он в 10 раз больше, чем нужно? Если да, то как раз `squeeze` должен решить проблему. Если нет, то проблема не в векторе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что QByteArray array выделяет не sizeof(myStruct) в размере структуры(140Б), а по несколько Кб, в итоге в вектор помещался в разы больший объем. Применение squeeze() к qbytearray уменьшает размер до 140Б, после чего вектор выделяет память всего лишь вдвое больше этого размера, что приемлемо.

```
socket.cpp

QVector<QByteArray> vector;
//myStruct моя структура на 50+ элементов 
QByteArray array = socket->read(sizeof(myStruct));
array.squeeze();
vector.push_back(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело в том, что вектор выделяет память с запасом (**Резервирует**). Например в STL-овском варианте вектора, **он выделяет памяти в 2 раза больше.** Не знаю, как в QVector, но скорее всего он выделяет тоже в 2 раза больше, чем нужно. **Это резервирование нужно чтобы ускорить работу вектора, ведь выделение памяти довольно затратная операция. При этом не ясно - сколько нужно будет скопировать информации в новый кусок памяти.** И если предыдущий кусок памяти весил 1 мегабайт, то вектору придётся довольно долго копировать всё это в новый кусок. Потому память выделяется с запасом.

Ещё: В следующий раз выкладывайте код полностью. Никто не хочет гадать как написан класс myStruct, что такое writeMessage, почему в socket.cpp не подключается файл socket.h и почему там же нет определения "vector" (Лучше назвать его иначе. Особенно если вы используете `using namespace std`, и у вас подключен vector) И вообще почему код просто так находиться в файле socket.cpp. Короче - вопросов очень много, и дать однозначный ответ из-за этого сложно. **Выкладывайте код полностью**

Comment: Если сложно ответить, не отвечайте...    Как понять  выражение "дать однозначный ответ из-за этого сложно",  в уже написанном ответе?  Или  это демонстрация того как преодолевать сложность?

Comment: В этих "кусках" кода было использование вектора, потому я и склоняюсь к тому, что это из-за вектора. Но это всё ещё не факт, ведь я не видел весь код и не могу сказать точно. Я написал это, чтобы человек  в следующий своих вопросах выкладывал код полностью. Конкретно в этом вопросе я никаких сложностей не испытал, но всё ещё - я не могу быть полностью уверен в правильности ответа только из-за того, что код выложен не полностью. Причём - любой человек не может быть уверен в правильности ответа в этом вопросе, опять же из-за не выложенного полностью кода. @ARHovsepyan

Comment: В qvector тоже выделяется в 2 раза больше памяти, но по факту память в 10 раз больше расходуется, а не в 2, что вызывает вопросы...

Comment: Провел небольшой тест - в 10 раз вектор просто не может выделить память. Вектор выделяет на 15 мегабайтов больше чем нужно, когда нужно всего 50 мегабайтов. То есть чтобы дойти до момента, когда он будет выделять в 10 раз больше - нужно где-то гигов 60. Я думаю, что тут ещё виноват менеджер памяти , или может qvector пишет перед основным блоком памяти какую-то информацию. Ну или автор просто  утрирует про 10 раз. @AndreyStashev

Comment: Сброшенные данные на диск можно удалить из памяти, в чем проблема?

Comment: Это точно вопрос ко мне, а не к автору? @ori

Comment: @ori Можно, но если есть убеждение что память не должна в таких размерах выделяться, то лучше сразу понять почему и поправить. Думал, что в этот момент QByteArray array = socket->read(sizeof(myStruct)); мой array может выделять не  sizeof(myStruct) памяти, а размер пакета, который может быть больше в несколько раз структуры?